# How to : use scp to append public key from linux(client) to windows (server with openssh running) in c:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, scp

I am trying to copy a client key from Linux(Ubuntu) to Windows server as an administrator user.
so far i am able to achieve this by using following steps:

> I am using bash in linux and powershell 7.3.4 in windows as an administrator.

1. Copy the public key from linux client to windows server:
   `scp ~/.ssh/public_key.pub Admin@WindowsServer:__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/`
2. ssh into windows server and check if there is `administrators_authorized_keys` file present in `C:\PROGRAMDATA\SSH\`
   If not, Create:
   `New-Item -Force -Path c:\PROGRAMDATA\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`
3. Set Permissions for administrators_authorized_keys file:
   `icacls C:\PROGRAMDATA\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys /inheritance:r /grant "Administrators:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"`
4. Append public_key.pub content into administrator_authorized_keys.
   `Get-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\public_key.pub | Add-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`

##### Now that the `administrators_authorized_keys` file has been created and configured, i am trying to have a different linux client to append its public key to this windows server (with `administrators_authorized_keys` configured) using `scp` in ONE-LINE.

I have tried something like this:
`scp Linux2Win_key.pub Admin@WindowsServer:__ProgramData__/ssh/ ; Get-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\Linux2Win_key.pub | Add-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`
Public key file is copied but NOT appended to the `administrator_authorized_keys` file. Got an Error:
`-bash: Add-Content: command not found`
`-bash: Get-Content: command not found`
Then i tried this :
`scp Linux2Win_key.pub Admin@WindowsServer:__ProgramData__/ssh/ ; cat __ProgramData__/ssh/Linux2Win_key.pub >> __ProgramData__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys`
Similar result, Public key file is copied but NOT appended to the `administrator_authorized_keys` file. Got an Error:
`-bash: __ProgramData__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys: No such file or directory`

Thoughts:
It looks like scp can only copy files and ssh-copy-id don't work in windows despite openssh can be enabled and ssh can be used in windows.

If you know any better way (rather than doing manually) to append public key to `authorized_keys` or `administrators_authorized_keys` in windows, please share. Thanks
I know, this is more of a windows issue and i have tried asking everywhere else.
I am sorry if it offends anyone that i present this issue in linux/unix fourm.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was just missing quotes!

When using `scp` command, after `Admin@WindowsServer:`, the content must be in quotes.

```
scp Linux2Win_key.pub Admin@WindowsServer:'__ProgramData__/ssh/ ; Get-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\Linux2Win_key.pub | Add-Content C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys'
```

This worked for me.